# How validate Order amount with payment made amount in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

```
<?php

namespace PayUIndia\Payu\Controller\Standard;


ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class Response extends \PayUIndia\Payu\Controller\PayuAbstract {

    public function execute() {

        /*$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $neworder = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
        $price = $neworder->getGrandTotal();*/
        //$testprice = $price==2000;


        $returnUrl = $this->getCheckoutHelper()->getUrl('checkout');
        $finalPrice = $this->getGrandTotal();

        try {
            $paymentMethod = $this->getPaymentMethod();
            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();


            if ($paymentMethod->validateResponse($params)) {




                     if(!$finalPrice){
                          $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Payment failed. Please try again or choose a different payment method'));
                $returnUrl = $this->getCheckoutHelper()->getUrl('checkout/onepage/failure');
                     }
                     else{
                $returnUrl = $this->getCheckoutHelper()->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success');
                $order = $this->getOrder();
                $payment = $order->getPayment();
                $paymentMethod->postProcessing($order, $payment, $params,$finalPrice);
            } 
            }

            else {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Payment failed. Please try again or choose a different payment method'));
                $returnUrl = $this->getCheckoutHelper()->getUrl('checkout/onepage/failure');
            }

        }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, $e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e)  {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('We can\'t place the order.'));
        }




        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post code which you have done for it & give more description so getting more idea about that.

Comment: @Yogesh I updated Question with code. I hopt you'll help me.

Comment: is it authorized or Capture ? Why this stuff done in controller ?

Comment: This is payubizz's official payment module. This is not validating product price with transaction made price.

Comment: No idea how this work ,  you can get payment information by extending this \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface

Comment: can I extend more than one class in magento 2

Comment: you can use by use key word.

Comment: can you explain me briefly

Comment: quite busy with work i will add code when i get time.

Comment: I hope you''ll send